# Mobile website only shows half loaded on android

Tags: android, mobile-website

I have made a mobile website for one of our clients. Two of the pages is looking really good, but the last page "Fokus lige nu" is only showing half of the page on a Android. If I look on the source, with the HTML source viewer app, it seems like it's loading all the content, but it's only showing half of it in the webbrowser. I have tested this on several mobiles but the with the same result.

The link to the website is http://www.prngo.dk/Default.aspx?ID=27812&Purge=True

Here are some details info about the page. The content is dynamic. We are using the jQuery plugin iScroll.

Is there any ideas why this is not working? Feel free to come with different solutions and I'll try them out!

Comment: working fine for me on both stock browser and dolphin hd beta (AKOP M6 4.0.4)